# Defining environment variables in Linux for Emacs access

Tags: emacs, elisp

On Macs, defining environment variables in the environment.plist will allow you to use environment variables in Emacs.app. On Linux, is there such an equivalent?

I don't want to use the environment variables in one of the shell or terminal emulators but also for `find-file` (C-x C-f), `shell-command` (C-!), etc. and I have a lot of paths defined as environment variables that would be helpful here. For instance, finding a file with `find-file` can be $WORK/projectname and so on.

I suppose the most straightforward way is to use `setenv` within `.emacs`, but as I have a lot of such variables it would be better if I could define it once in an external file and have Emacs read it in.

**Edit:** Sorry for the confusion. This question is specifically addressing issue of Emacs access, as variables defined in ~/.bashrc is not available to Emacs until shell, eshell, or term is invoked.

Comment: I think so, but unfortunately no solution is presented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to access the variables in your `.bashrc` you need to launch emacs from a bash shell. If you just click on an icon then the `.bashrc` is not read and you won't have access to your variables.

If you absolutely cannot launch emacs from a bash shell, find an init file that is loaded by your desktop environment. In my case it is `.xsession`. Any variable I export in it will be available to emacs.

To access environment variable use `getenv`.

Comment: right, however .bashrc doesn't look the suitable place for the OP's task. Recommend a shell-script exporting it, as suggested above. Otherwise bash sticks with these settings.

Comment: I did end up writing a shell script to create an elisp file (from .bashrc) with a succesion of variable definitions using setenv. However, I will look into the .xsession (or .xsessionrc, .xprofile?) - I think that's what I was looking for originally...

Answer (score 3):

here a script which defines several environment variables, read by Emacs in batch mode

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode/view/head:/test/python-mode-tests.sh

from lisp getting $HOME for example use (getenv "HOME")

Comment: Interesting - so you actually define the environment variables in the Emacs call. That did not occur to me, but I have instead generated a separate elisp file which I read into my .emacs.

Answer (score 1):

If you define environment variables in ~/.bashrc they are available in the user shell for all commands.
The right syntax is:

```
export VARIABLE="value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your `.bashrc` in your home directory, where you can add your own aliases, define environment variables and add paths for your custom scripts.